# Allow marked up input in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

So it seems it should be possible to allow users to mark up their inputs in Shiny just as I can mark up my input to this text message -- bold, italics, hyperlinks, etc.

The only option I have found is the shinyMCE package which has not been updated for many years and which no longer works.

Are there any other options?